# Implementation of a 8-to-256 decoder using BJTs

Tags: bjt, computer-architecture

I'm designing an 8-to-256 decoder for an SRAM module I'm building for an home-made 8-bit BJT computer.

This is what I've got, which is the straightforward and trivial way: [image: schematic]

However, the design requires more than 2000 transistors and about 300 resistors, assuming the use of a common resistor for each BITx and BITx_NOT output.

That's almost 7000 pins to solder, and would require an immense amount of space and time to do.

What are some ways I can optimize the design to require less transistors?

(By the way, I'm aware that the implementation of the actual RAM will require just as many transistors. What I'm trying to do is to only do that once. :)

Comment: Wow. I think your willing to learn would be better rewarded if you had a look at verilog, rather than soldering 2000 transistors.

Comment: @dim was about to suggest that as well. Look at FPGAs - still all the fun of designing your own computer, but you don't have to solder all the transistors. As an aside, now you know why ICs were developed - the original computers were literally the size of shipping containers.

Comment: I'd like to design something with BJT transistors mostly because I love the feel of "old" electronics, and I'd love to have the original question answered, be it just for the sake of learning. :)

@TomCarpenter I'd love to work on FPGAs. Can you point me to something affordable to start? I'm a student, I can't spend much.

Comment: @RiccardoBestetti Cheap Cyclone FPGA dev kits will be far less than 2000 BJTs...

Comment: @TomCarpenter Not so sure about that, I can get 2000 2N3904 for about 50€. Anyway, looking at Cyclones on ALTERA's website, I really wouldn't know what to buy.

Comment: @RiccardoBestetti [DE0 Nano](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=139&No=593) is only about $80. You can get much cheaper dev kits on eBay (older models like Cyclone II boards are $25-$50 range).

Comment: A word of caution when evaluating various logic circuits made of transistors and diodes when used as building-blocks for something larger: The outputs must be capable of driving the inputs of succeeding stages. Watch out for voltage drops.

Comment: @TomCarpenter thank you very much for your pointers!

Comment: @Tut yes, that is something I thought about. Am I correct at thinking that it would be enough to amplify the signal through a BJT beetween different stages/blocks?

Comment: Probably, but you just need to take it into account. Also consider fan-out as you will often need to drive more than one input. This is especially true for bus signals such as address and data. [Here](http://www.play-hookey.com/digital_electronics/dtl_gates.html) is a brief on Diode-Transistor logic which mentions the transistor as an output buffer in the first line.

Comment: @Tut thank you for your input and the link. I will definitely keep that in mind when designing my system. I really don't think it'll be a problem, as the architecture will be extremely simple and I don't think I'll need to drive more than 4-5 inputs with the same signal. Worst case, I'll run the buses at a slightly higher voltage.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement a decoder by discrete components you can use DTL and a diode matrix:

Here is an example of a 2-to-4 decoder that explains the basic principle:

- for each address line create an inverted signal
- for each output create an AND gate that connects to the inverted address line for a 0 address bit and to the non-inverted address line for 1 address bit.

Probably you have to buffer the outputs.
I't won't be very high speed (depending on the pull up resistors).
Yes, you need lots of diodes (8 × 256 = 2048).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNHsmm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Well, it requires just as many diodes as my solution requires transistors, but it's 1 less leg to solder. :)

Comment: Since a transistor contains two diodes that's still an improvement of factor 2 (not to mention the fact that your  solution with 8 transistors in a row wouldn't work :-)

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: ...because of the voltage drop in each transistor. Even if all inputs are high the emitter of the top transistor might be to high to be turned on.

Comment: Looks like that's not the case at 5V - http://tinyurl.com/huj2ohm - the LED is lit, which means that after the 8 transistors there is still enough tension to drive a BJT, which should be all I need to make this work. Having said that, your solution is still the better one and probably the one I will use when/if I really try to build this thing.

Comment: There might be enough voltage to light a LED and of course you can drive another BJT with that voltage but the H level at the output will be substantially lower (I guess ca. 1V) than the H levels at the Input. That means you can not chain more than 1 or 2 such gates.

Comment: Ok - I get what you're saying. But can't I just buffer the output of the last transistor?

Comment: Yes, I think that would work, but it costs another transitor. With the DTL and diode matrix shown in my answer you would not need that. You need a buffer only in case you require higher currents at H Level, but not if you just want to chain more DTL gates at the output (becasue H level will be very close to 5V).

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that's an ambitious project. It's hard to know where to begin in terms of responding — and that's why it's a bit too broad for the Q&A format we use here.

First of all, nobody ever — not even "back in the day" — built large random-access memories out of discrete BJT technology. Before ICs became available, computers were still using mostly magnetic technology for storage: disks, drums and cores. So as a "retro" project, it has no basis in actual history. (And now you're finding out why! :-)

Second, if you're building large AND gates by stringing transistors together in series as shown in your schematic, your design is doomed to failure, or at least extreme frustration, as a result of the widely shifting logic levels in different parts of the circuitry.

You really want to pick a single implementation technology, such as RTL NOR gates or DTL NAND gates, and stick with that technology to build all of the higher-order circuits that your computer needs. If you were to do this, you'd be following a well-traveled historical path — famous computers such as the PDP-8 and even the first Cray supercomputers were implemented using this approach.

---

Just as an example, if I were tempted to create a computer out of discrete transistors, I would be inclined to create a standard PCB module something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftAKX4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This module implements up to three DTL NAND-type gates. The solder bridges give some flexibility — you could have any combination ranging from three 3-input gates, to one 7-input gate and two inverters. If you depopulate some components, you could have an 8- or 9-input gate.

Two modules (6 gates) could implement a full D-type master-slave flip-flop, although I would consider designing the system to use a 2-phase clock so that the individual flip-flops could be simpler. If the design requires a lot of flip-flops, I might design a second module that holds a pair of them.

The module would be laid out as a SIP (single inline package), with all 14 pins along one edge. I would plug these modules into a wire-wrap prototyping board like the one below, which could hold a few hundred of them.

[image: wirewrap proto board]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, the project is ambitious, and I'm starting to realize that maybe it is too much so. I'm not sure how sticking to a single implementation technology would help my project.
About logic levels, what if I just use the SRAMxxx_ENBL signal to drive a 5V signal through a BJT? Wouldn't that allow push the logic level back up to 5V, thus eliminating the problem?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean by *"drive a 5V signal through a BJT"*. In any sort of emitter-follower configuration, you're going to get a voltage offset -- as well as a voltage gain that's less than unity. Any practical implementation of logic needs to include voltage gain, which is why common-emitter amplifiers are typically used as buffers.

Comment: I understand that I'm going to get a voltage offset, and that this offset is gradually going to degrade my signal. What I meant is that this signal can be amplified back to 5V voltage (minus, of course, the voltage drop from the transistor) when needed with a PNP transistor in emitter-follower configuration.
Also, what do you mean by "picking a single implementation technology"? How would only using, for example, RTL NOR gates, solve the problem you've outlined?

Comment: Ok - I just realized that I got all the amplifying part in reverse. Still, my question remains. :)

Comment: That's where this topic gets to be too broad to address here. The design of a logic family involves many subtleties. [The tutorial](http://www.play-hookey.com/digital_electronics/) that @Tut linked to is a good one to start with. The basic concept is that you really want to separate the design of the logic from the design of the circuitry so that you can address them one at a time. The *best* way to do that is to make sure every gate has consistent input and output characteristics (in terms of voltage and current). The *easiest* way to do that is to use a single type of gate.